# Anyone know of a WeakReferenceCollection to hold listeners

Tags: java, collections

I would like to avoid class loader leaks due to un-removed listeners. To facilitate this i believe weak or soft references to listeners would help. Strictly the only Collection methods i need are add() and iterator().

Are there any foss libraries with a Set or List that uses Weak or Soft References.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, otherwise i will write my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually use `WeakHashSet` for this purpose. Just use `null` for all of the values.

*EDIT*
WeakHashMap for WeakHashSet and Boolean.TRUE for values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a java.util.WeakHashMap. I am not sure whether parallel for List and Set in JDK, though it should be fairly simple to write a WeakList using WeakReferences. There is an example implementation of [WeakReferenceList](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/WeakReferencelistusesjavalangrefWeakReferencestostoreitscontents.htm).

Please note that storing listeners as WeakReferences can be dangerous, as many people code listeners as anonymous classes which can easily get out of reach and gc-ed.

Comment: I am using the handler pattern where by i return a remover for each added listener. The remover holds a reference to the listener which it uses to remove from the collection. The proper way to use this is of course to keep and call the remover when it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Was trivial wrote my own using WeakHashMap as the bucket.